# If I get a second SSD will there be a performance change by moving the operating system?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, performance, windows-10

I have my OS on an SSD with a HDD storage drive as a secondary. 
I've had the SSD for about half a year now, and it is starting to get full.

If I get a second SSD will there be a performance boost or decrease by moving the OS off the old SSD and onto the new?
Or should I clear everything off the first except the OS and leave the second drive empty?

Intuitively I feel like moving the OS off the old drive is the better option, but this is just guesswork, I have no real source backing it up.

Comment: What's the point of having two SSDs if one is empty?

Comment: Well it wouldn't stay empty long. I was thinking OS on one, programs on the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would get the best performance by placing the OS files on the fastest SSD. If they are identical you could raid them for increased performance. They can be raided even if they aren't identical but you could end up with unused space if there is a size mismatch.

Comment: Isn't there some kind of relation between the amount of free space on the drive and performance?

Comment: I would say its easier for files to get fragmented when the drive is almost full since the free space may not be a single continuous area. But files can get fragmented even if the there's plenty of free space on the drive. The upside is that an SSD don't suffer much (if any?) from file fragmentation since it lacks physical arms that move back and forth over platters seeking data that non-SSD drives have.